# Confused with syntax, calling a JS function with an input button

Tags: javascript, xhtml, dom-events

I am having troubles understanding the xhtml syntax for calling a function with an input button. I have searched for this, but cannot find a clear explanation.

This snippet of code is from my book, and it works ok, but I'm not sure exactly how the following line works:

```
onclick="checkGrade(document.gradeForm.grade.value);"
```

From what I can figure out, `gradeForm` is the form, and then `grade` is the switch statement? So would you use `Foo` if you had another switch statement called foo inside the `checkGrades` function? And I am not sure what document or value are for inside the `onClick checkGrade` function.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkGrade(grade) {
    switch (grade.toUpperCase()) {
    case "A":
    window.alert("Your grade is excellent.")
    break;
case "B":
    window.alert("Your grade is good.")
    break;
case "C":
    window.alert("Your grade is fair.")
    break;
case "D":
    window.alert("You are barely passing.")
    break;
case "F":
    window.alert("You failed.")
    break;
default: 
    window.alert("You did not enter a valid letter grade.");
    break;
    }
}
</script>


<p>Please enter your grade below:</p>
<form action="#" name="gradeForm">
    <input type="text" name="grade" />
    <input type="button" value="Check Grade" onclick="checkGrade(document.gradeForm.grade.value);" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `grade` refers to the textbox. You're passing the value of the textbox into the `checkGrade` function. The `switch` statement is running over the `grade` variable, which holds the value of the `grade` textbox.

You can't really "name" a switch statement. The argument to the `switch` represents the value you are testing.

`document` represents your HTML document, and `value` is the value of the textbox named `grade`. On another note, it is not recommended to use the `onClick` attribute in XHTML/HTML. Unobtrusive Javascript is preferred, where you bind a handler to the button. For more details, I recommend reading up on the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM), specifically [The DOM and Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript).

How old is this book you're using?

Comment: Wow thanks! That makes it very clear now. The book I am using is fairly recent, but they go into the DOM towards the back of the book. I will keep the last paragraph in mind when I get to the DOM. Thanks again!